# Access to IIS global application settings

Tags: c#, iis-7.5, appsettings

Is it possible to access for global application settings(defined on IIS Home screen -> Application Settings). I believe that global web.config should inherited by all applications, but I have tried

```
var myGlobalSetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyGlobalSetting"]
```

and

```
var appSettings = (NameValueCollection)HttpContext.Current.GetSection("appSettings");
var myGlobalSetting = appSettings["MyGlobalSetting"];
```

Both return null. I don't have anything that override or clear settings.

What I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: IIRC, those requests for settings only ask the application's web.config.

Comment: Hmm, so why than Applications Settings on IIS Home screen named as they named - confusing? And what for are they then?

Comment: There's an [appSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228154(v=vs.100).aspx) node in the web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WebConfigurationManager`:

```
var myGlobalSetting = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyGlobalSetting"];
```